# How to joint Graph-Cordinates in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image]

I am plotting output with plt.quiver.So it gives me a 2D field of the array. But as I attached in Image, I wanted to joint coordinates at the upper border as well as at lower border and also around an object(looks like a circle at lower of the graph).

I know the x and y coordinates of the upper and lower border, but I am not able to joint it or make it darker black, so I can see very appropriate boundary and object.

Is there any easy function in matplotlib?

```
plt.quiver(X,Y,U_pretrain,V_pretrain,M_pretrain, cmap=plt.cm.jet, clim=[0.0,1.0])
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that you know the x and y coordinates of the upper and lower border, after your call to `plt.quiver` it should be enough to call `plt.plot`

```py
plt.plot(lower_x, lower_y, color='k')
plt.plot(upper_x, upper_y, color='k')
```

Comment: Actually x and y coordinates of upper and lower side are mixed..not separated, so when I plot it, it draws a line up down , down up. I am thinking about this one..ax.plot(t, mu*t, lw=1, label='population mean', color='black', ls='--'), but here array t should be iterable

Comment: Okay. Could you then separate out the upper and lower? Something like ```x_lower = x[::2]``` and ```x_upper = x[1::2]```?

Comment: No.In this Graph total 1700 points there. And at evry points it has some velocity value, and at boundry and over object shape(rectangular. circle) velocity value is zero. So I got anyway to sort out which points lies on the boundry lines and on object shape..then I got (199,2) points with x any y coordinates.And then I wanted to make this points Dark colored.

Comment: Okay, without having the points separated into the two boundaries you won't be able to plot them joined up. But to plot the (199,2) x, y coordinates as black it would be sufficient to do ```plt.plot(data[:, 0], data[:, 1], color='k')```.

Comment: You may still be able to separate the boundaries. Without having your data it's difficult to know though. But something like ```x_lower = X[(U == 0) * (V == 0) * (Y < Y.mean())]``` and ```y_lower = Y[(U == 0) * (V == 0) * (Y < Y.mean())]``` might work